# How to load a a collection of users\factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0, `rspec-rails 2` and `Factory` gems. In order to test a controller `index` action I would like to load a collection of users\factories.

*Example* (the following code doesn't work):

```
describe "GET index" do
  let(:users) { 3.times(Factory(:user)) }

  it "should ..." do
    users.should ...
  end
end
```

Using the above code I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:users) { 3.times(Factory(:user)) }
ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

**What can I do to load factories in to `users` variable?**

---

**UPDATE** ... and if in the above code I have `Factory(:user, :account => Factory.build(:account))` instead of `Factory(:user)` *how can I load factories?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`let(:users) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 3) }`

Comment: And if I have something like this: `Factory(:user, :account => Factory.build(:account))`. How can I load factories?

Comment: Try `FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 3, :account => Factory.build(:account))`